# Where do I put the code to simplify the controller?

Tags: php, symfony

My example is simple. I have **Users**. They can submit **Ideas**. Everybody else can **Support** these ideas with **credits**. When a User want to support an idea, I need to check if he has enough credit, etc. Where do I put this code ?

```
/**
* @Route("/support/{ideaSlug}", name="support_new")
*/
public function newAction(Request $request, $ideaSlug)
{
    $support = new Support();
    $form = $this->createForm(SupportType::class, $support);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if($user->getCredit() > 0) {
            $idea = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Idea')->findOneBy(['slug' => $ideaSlug]);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($support);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('support_index'));
    }

    return $this->render('support/new.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Do I need a user **service** like :

```
namespace AppBundle\Utils;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use AppBundle\Entity\Idea;

class User
{
    protected $em;
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->$user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    public support(Idea $idea)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Or do I put it in the **entity** class ?

Comment: Can't really put it in the entity since the entity has no access to the entity manager.  Your UserSupport service is probably your best bet.

Comment: You could think about a custom validator (Your needed is about validation). Of course you can decouple the login in a service and use it in a custom constraint

Comment: @Matteo makes a good point.  The form should not be considered valid unless the credit check passes.  At which point it becomes a simple persist.

Comment: I will try with a custom validator.

Comment: Maybe just use voter...